# first and second order approximations of mean and variance

Tags: self-study, inference

$X_1, X_2,...,X_n$ are iid $N(\theta,1/2)$ random variables. $\bar{X}^3$ can be used to estimate $\mu^3_X = \theta^3$

How do you determine the first-order and second-order approximations of the mean of $\bar{X}^3$?

additionally, how do you determine the first order approximation of the variance?

I know for the first order approximation, you use
$$g(X_n) = g(\mu_x) + (X_n - \mu_x)g^{'}(\mu_x)$$ but I am having trouble figuring out how to tie this problem into this fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first order approximation to the variance of $g(X)$, you need to set up a variance term on the left hand side (l.h.s.) of your first order approximation.  The first step is to get a squared deviation term on the l.h.s. by subtracting $g(\mu)$ from both sides, then squaring:

$$(g(X)-g(\mu))^2 = (x-\mu)^2g'(\mu)^2$$

To convert the l.h.s. to a variance, take the expectation:

$$\sigma^2_g = \text{E}(g(X)-g(\mu))^2 = \text{E}(x-\mu)^2g'(\mu)^2$$

Substituting results in:

$$\sigma^2_g = \sigma^2_xg'(\mu)^2$$

We should keep in mind that all those "$=$" are relative to the first order approximation, not a true relationship between $\sigma^2_g$ and $\sigma^2_x$.

The procedure for the second order approximation to the mean is similar, and, during it, you'll see why we have to go to the second order.  Let's write out the approximation:

$$g(x) = g(\mu) + (x-\mu)g'(\mu) + {1\over 2}(x-\mu)^2g''(\mu)$$

Here we already have what we want on the l.h.s., so all we need to do is take expectations:

$$\text{E}g(x) = \text{E}g(\mu) + \text{E}(x-\mu)g'(\mu) + {1\over 2}\text{E}(x-\mu)^2g''(\mu)$$

Noting that $\text{E}g(\mu) = g(\mu)$ (as it is a constant) and $\text{E}(x-\mu)g'(\mu) = 0$ (as $g'(\mu)$ is a constant and $\text{E}x = \mu$), we rewrite the r.h.s. as:

$$\text{E}g(x) = g(\mu) + {1\over 2}\sigma^2_xg''(\mu)$$

We have to go to the second order because the term $(x-\mu)$ disappears when we take the expectation, so the first order approximation is just $\text{E}g(x) = g(\mu)$, not what we're looking for.

Comment: so if we were to write the first order approximation of the mean in terms of $\theta$, would it just be $\theta^3$? Just want to make sure I'm understanding this part correctly

Comment: Yes, that's correct, except that it would be $\bar{X}^3$ as estimated from the sample.  The first order and zeroth order approximations are the same.

Comment: By following these steps and plugging in 1/2 for the variance, I tried to solve this problem. So for the second order approximation of the mean of $X^3$, in terms of $\theta$, I came up with $\theta^2 + 3/2\theta$ and for the first order approximation of the variance, in terms of $\theta$, I came up with $9/2\theta^2$. Just wanted to check that this was the correct way to go about this

Comment: $g(\theta) = \theta^3$, not $\theta^2$, and this has affected both your answers.  Other than that, yes, that's the correct way to go about it.